# Error representar un valor en un grafico en Google data studio

Tags: google-data-studio

Tengo un problema, tengo un valor numero que es decimal, es decir, por ejemplo "6.1" y lo pongo en un grafico, este grafico falla y salta el siguiente error.
Da igual en que dimension ponga los valores decimales que el grafico da error, las dimensiones de la tabla son las mismas que las del grafico.
[image: DATA STUDIO NO PUEDE CONECTARSE A SU CONJUNTO DE DATOS]

Comment: Trata de [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/540393/edit) tu pregunta y mostrarnos que es lo que estás intentando hacer para darte una respuesta acorde.

Comment: @Liyo ya esta, es que tampoco hay mucho más que decir creo. Gracias